# Toggle Open Close Master and Modular Panel

Tags: javascript, extendscript, adobe-scriptui

```
var seg1 = true;
var seg2 = true;
var seg3 = true;

function segOne() {
    if (seg1 == true) {
        seg1 = false;
        //do close panel seg 1 
    } else {
        seg1 = true;
        //do open panel seg 1 
    }
}

function segTwo() {
    if (seg2 == true) {
        seg12 = false;
        //do close panel  seg 2
    } else {
        seg2 = true;
        //do open panel  seg 2
    }
}

function segThree() {
    if (seg3 == true) {
        seg3 = false;
        //do close panel  seg 3
    } else {
        seg3 = true;
        //do open panel  seg 3
    }
}


function opencloseAll() {
    segOne()
    segTwo()
    segThree()
    }
    
masterBtn.addEventListener('click', opencloseAll);
    
seg1Btn.addEventListener('click', segOne);

seg2Btn.addEventListener('click', segTwo);

seg3Btn.addEventListener('click', segThree);
```

Hi forum, I made a panel that can be toggle close and expend panel.

For now masterBtn do, it do open all and close all segment which is correct.

My question is how to do open any single segment (for example open segTwo) but when i click on masterBtn it close only opened segment.

I know I need more conditions but I cant find a right logic more than this.

Please help, Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the HTML as well?

Comment: Im sorry, I made it in Adobe Extendscript Toolkit for scriptUI panel. //do close panel where all the calculation for +- panel size.